# Exporting HTML table to Excel uing Javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel

I was trying to use a javascript function for exporting html table to excel. Here is the code:

```
 var tableToExcel = (function () {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
 return function (table, name, filename) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

    document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
    document.getElementById("dlink").click();

}
})()
```

but it doesn't work for IE. Is their any workaround for IE?

Comment: what about it "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error in the developer console?

Comment: IE8 or lower do not support data: url schema. IE9 and upper do not support data: url schema on links.